# Change one function call for another

Tags: debugging, winapi, disassembly

I have a closed-source win32 executable which plays a sound; the sound is hardcoded in, what I'm trying to do is get it to play a *different* sound.

I'm using x32dbg and I can find the function call I want to change - it seems to be using OpenAL to play the sound, and if I find alSourcePlay and just return instead of invoking it, there's no sound, as I expect.

My plan was to swap it for a call to PlaySoundW because the program already includes references to that library, and I could just get it to play a wave file in the same directory. I've examined disassemblies of the way to invoke the PlaySoundW call, and I've tried modifying the point where the call is made to copy them in, but because there are more instructions going in than are currently there, the exe immediately crashes when you resume running.

I've found lots of articles about the start of this process (mostly cracking ones e.g. finding a function call in an exe and skipping it) but not one that covers what I'm trying to do.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Is there a better or different way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is possible. If you follow the arguments of the function, you can locate the binary of the sound and change that data to your new sound.  You will need to look up the function arguments.  I would reverse the file, find the offset of the function and then modify it.